# Size of structure

Tags: c#, struct

It is possible to get size of struct using

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(mystruct));
```

Is it possible to get size of a part of a structure(for example I pass to function the last field of a structure and it returns sum of sizes of previous fields)?
As I understand is it possible using reflection?

Comment: Why do you need this? Are you really marshalling anything or just abusing the marshaller to offer something that should not be used in C# in the first place?

Comment: I am reading struct from Binary stream and i have to get just one byte instead of reading whole structure.
And instead of calculating the offset of that byte manually I'd like to do it programmatically

Comment: If you're going to use other fields from the structure, I think you should just un-serialize/load the whole binary stream anyway. Especially since it's the last field you need in your example - you'd be skipping over bytes to find the one you need, only to seek back and read the other fields.

Comment: Thanks for comments.
I can ask this question in other way is it possible to get offset of field in the structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte b1;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte b2;
    [FieldOffset(7)]
    public int i1;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public int i2;
}

class Program
{
    static FieldOffsetAttribute GetFieldOffset(string fieldName)
    {
        return (FieldOffsetAttribute)typeof(SomeStruct)
            .GetField(fieldName)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldOffsetAttribute), false)[0];
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someStruct = new SomeStruct { b1 = 1, b2 = 2, i1 = 3, i2 = 4 };

        Console.WriteLine("field b1 offset: {0}", GetFieldOffset("b1").Value);
        Console.WriteLine("field b2 offset: {0}", GetFieldOffset("b2").Value);
        Console.WriteLine("field i1 offset: {0}", GetFieldOffset("i1").Value);
        Console.WriteLine("field i2 offset: {0}", GetFieldOffset("i2").Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Prints: 
field b1 offset: 0
field b2 offset: 3
field i1 offset: 7
field i2 offset: 12

Comment: That is what i was looking for.. But i think it will not work with structures that are not marked with [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]

Comment: Yes, It will not work. Only for structures with this attribute. You can't achieve this for arbitrary structure. Is this a problem? Or you can't change existing code for that?

Answer (score 2):

The memory layout of a struct is not discoverable in .NET.  The JIT compiler takes advantage of this, it re-orders the fields of a struct to get a more efficient layout.  This plays havoc with any attempt to use the struct in a way that bypasses the normal marshaling mechanisms.  Yes, Marshal.SiseOf() produces a size for a struct.  But that size is only valid after using Marshal.StructureToPtr().

A direct answer to your question: no, you can't discover the size, not even with Reflection.  By design.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure but I think it's impossible due to possible optimization and alignment issues.

Comment: IIRC .the CLR can rearrange the fields of a type to give better layout, unless you use `StructLayoutAttribute`.